# The difference between a matrix valued random variable and an $n \times p$ matrix of data

Tags: probability, statistics, soft-question, random-matrices

So I am totally new to the field of random matrices, but I was not sure about how they are applied. According to Wikipedia, a random matrix is "a matrix-valued random variable—that is, a matrix some or all of whose elements are random variables." However, I don't understand where I would use a random matrix in a statistical model versus a random matrix. In other words, in multivariate statistical analysis we usually have an $n \times p$ data matrix, where given an observation $X_i$, we collect various $p$ attributes of this observation, so $X_{i,1}, . . ., X_{i,p}$. So why can't we represent the elements of a random matrix as an $n \times p$ matrix like we use in multivariate statistics? Sorry if this question is really naive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have described for $X$ is just the matrix of *predictors*. A random matrix is quite different. Lets start with a perhaps more familiar example, a bivariate gaussian random variable. This "variable" is a *vector valued* random variable $X=(X_1,X_2)$, where the two components of $X$ can co-vary with each other (i.e., to get an "oblong" shaped gaussian density).

Therefore, a "vector valued" random variable is associated with a joint distribution, $p(x,y,z...)$ of a set of scalar-valued random variables.

Generalizing this further, if each component is itself a vector, then you get a "matrix valued" random variable. This may be useful when you are describing the joint distribution of a set of vector-valued quantities. For example, let $X=(\nabla P,\nabla T, \nabla v)$, where $P$ is pressure,$T$ is temperature, and $v$ is the wind velocity for a given point. If these quantities are not independent of one another, then it makes sense to treat them as part of a single, *matrix valued* random variable $X$

Comment: Ahh, I get what you are saying. Haha, why could I not find such a simple explanation in all of the books I have looked into :). So a good example would be the gradient of pressure, where there is a pressure in the <x,y,z> dimensions. I can understand the utility of this if you want to separate the correlations between item within the same matrix column versus correlations between columns in the same matrix. Any suggestions on where to find a good introduction to this topic @Bey.

Comment: @krishnab unfortunately, I've used up all my knowledge of matrix-valued random variables. I've never used them in my work, but I had to understand them for the odd paper or two that I had to review.

Comment: Haha, I understand totally. Thanks so much for the explanation above.